# How to handle one to many relationship in TanStack Table (React-Table V8)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, html-table, react-table, react-table-v8

I'm currently trying [Tanstack Table](https://tanstack.com/table/v8), which is a great library!

What I'm trying to do is build up a table that looks like this:

[image: Table that I want]

My data come from an API with this type:

```
type Accounting = {
  category: string;
  total: number; // Sum of all expenses
  expenses: {
    name: string;
    value: number;
  }[];
};
```

Here is what I've got so far:

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      columnHelper.accessor("category", {
        header: "Category",
        id: "category",
        cell: (info) => {
          return (
            <>
              {info.row.getCanExpand() && (
                <button
                  {...{
                    onClick: info.row.getToggleExpandedHandler(),
                    style: { cursor: "pointer" },
                    className: "mr-2",
                  }}
                >
                  {info.row.getIsExpanded() ? (
                    <Chevron direction="down" />
                  ) : (
                    <Chevron direction="right" />
                  )}
                </button>
              )}
              {info.getValue()}
            </>
          );
        },
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor("expenses", {
        header: undefined,
        id: "expense-name",
        cell: (info) => {
          // FIXME : this returns a table of objects, I want one row per expense
          return info.getValue();
        },
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor("expenses", {
        aggregationFn: "sum",
        id: "expense-value",
        header: "Expense",
        cell: (info) => {
          // FIXME : this returns a table of objects, I want one row per expense
          return info.getValue();
        },
      }),
    ],
    []
  );

  const grouping = React.useMemo(() => ["category"], []);

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    state: {
      grouping,
      expanded,
    },
    getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
    getGroupedRowModel: getGroupedRowModel(),
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    onExpandedChange: setExpanded,
    autoResetExpanded: false,
  });
```

The problem here is that I've got a One-To-Many relationship between one category and multiple expenses for this category.

The above code does not work because tanstack table tries to render a list of objects (a list of expense).

I haven't figure out how Tanstack Table can handle this ? Should I override some sort of render method ? Is Tanstack Table the good choice for this kind of data ?

Respectfully.

Answer (score 22):

You can draw a lot from the [React Table Expanding Example](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/examples/react/expanding).

The critical part which you are missing is the [`getSubRows`](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/table#getsubrows) function on the table.  Rather than rendering the individual expenses within the `cell` of the parent category, we want to create a new row in the table for each expense.

Our two columns are a title and a number.  For a top-level `Accounting` object, it is the `category` and the `total`.  For an individual expense, it's the `name` and `value`.  Since those are different properties, we'll need to do some mapping.

Let's start really simple and define those two columns for the top-level objects:

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
  () => [
    columnHelper.accessor("category", {
      header: "Category",
      id: "category"
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("total", {
      header: "Expense",
      id: "expense-value"
    })
  ],
  []
);
```

[image]

---

Now, let's add in the expand functionality. (You do not need the grouping functionality.)

We will store the `expanded` state in the component and pass it to the table, syncing changes through the `onExpandedChange` option.

We will add a new `getSubRows` option to your table.  This is a function that takes the parent `Accounting` object and returns an array of child `Accounting` objects.  As explained earlier, we need to rename some properties to make the interfaces match up.  Our `columns` config expects an object with `category` and `total`.  I set an empty array of `expenses` here because the child rows do not have children of their own.

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState<ExpandedState>({});

const table = useReactTable({
  data,
  columns,
  state: {
    expanded
  },
  getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
  getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  onExpandedChange: setExpanded,
  getSubRows: (originalRow) =>
    originalRow.expenses.map((expense) => ({
      category: expense.name,
      total: expense.value,
      expenses: []
    }))
});
```

For your columns, the only change that I made from the previous is to display an expand/contract button on the parent rows (which you already had in your attempt).

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
  () => [
    columnHelper.accessor("category", {
      header: "Category",
      id: "category",
      cell: (info) => {
        return (
          <>
            {info.row.getCanExpand() && (
              <button onClick={info.row.getToggleExpandedHandler()}>
                {info.row.getIsExpanded() ? "-" : "+"}
              </button>
            )}
            {info.getValue()}
          </>
        );
      }
    }),
    columnHelper.accessor("total", {
      header: "Expense",
      id: "expense-value"
    })
  ],
  []
);
```

[image]

Now we have fully-functional row expansion.  It's not beautiful but I'll leave it to you to add styling.

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-v8-expanded-rows-1cpdju?file=/src/Table.tsx)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Exactly what I was looking for, and really well explained :)

Comment: Can you provide an edited version that expand one and collapse other?